# Problem in Importing File

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am importing File **"FieldActivityViewController.h"**.But Showing an error

> "/Users/rupeshnandha/Downloads/AQMD
>   Release 3/Classes/InputChoice.h:22:0
>   Expected specifier-qualifier-list
>   before 'FieldActivityViewController'
>   in /Users/rupeshnandha/Downloads/AQMD
>   Release 3/Classes/InputChoice.h"

As is a code Written in **"InputChoice.h"**

```
#import "FieldActivityViewController.h"

@protocol InputChoiceProtocol <NSObject>

@required
-(void) inputChoiceSelectedIndex :(int) index;

@end


@interface InputChoice : UIViewController {
    //NSString *keyString;
    FieldActivityViewController *field_act;

    NSMutableArray *selectionArray;
    IBOutlet UITableView *table;
    NSObject<InputChoiceProtocol> *delegate;
   // IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *selectionArray;
@property (nonatomic,retain) FieldActivityViewController *field_act;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSObject<InputChoiceProtocol> *delegate;
@end
```

Comment: Sounds like there may be a problem with the declaration of `FieldActivityViewController` in FieldActivityViewController.h. Perhaps you should post relevant code from that header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `@class FieldActivityViewController`

Comment: @Rupesh :It's not @Jhaliya , it's @maheswaran  ... edit your comment :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not the good practice to import the application classes in .h files.

Try with **forward class declaration**  and import you `FieldActivityViewController` file in `.h`

Use with **forward class declaration**  `@class FieldActivityViewController;`  at the place of your `import` statement.

Comment: I have tried that i am geting another error in .m file at this line [field_act.txtfdFieldActivity setText:[[selectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] retain]];

Comment: Yep. Usually, when you see imports of other headers in a .h file it's to import a protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely cause is that you have a circular dependency.  `InputChoice.h` imports `FieldActivityViewController.h` and `FieldActivityViewController.h` imports `InputChoice.h` (not necessarily directly).

The best solution is to move the imports out of the header file into the `.m` file and put

```
@class FieldActivityViewController;
```

in `InputChoice.h` and

```
@class InputChoice
```

in `FieldActivityViewController.h` (or whichever header has `InputChoic.h` in it.